# Adjust spacing in table of content

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I am very new to TeX. I have a Latex template for writing a thesis. I'm trying to report only the part of the template that I think are important.. please tell me if I'm omitting something!

I am including chapters and automatically create the table of content in this way:

```
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents        % Indice

\input{cap1}
\input{cap2}
\input{cap3}
\input{cap4}
```

now, in `cap1.tex` I have added 2 preface chapter in this way:

```
\chapter{Preface}
    \begin{flushright}\begin{small}
    \end{small}\end{flushright}
        Lorem ipsum ...

\chapter{Organization of this book}
    \begin{flushright}\begin{small}
    \end{small}\end{flushright}
        Lorem ipsum ...

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{flushright}\begin{small}
    \end{small}\end{flushright}
        \section {Definition of the problem}
            Lorem ipsum ...
```

And this show exactly what I want to do but.. in the table of content I have a space between *Preface* and *Organization of this book* that I don't want. It is the normal space between the chapters but I want this first 2 preface chapter to be without space in the ToC.

I have tried to change `\chapter` with `\section` but the 2 preface are indented.

So.. how to remove the space between the 2 preface chapter?

Comment: What do you mean by *space*? A vertical space between the entries? They should appear as normal chapters since you are using `{toc}{chapter}`.

Comment: yes, a vertical space between the entries. Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: EDIT: with `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` I have removed the addtoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `book` class, by default, adds 10pt between chapter entries in the ToC; you can remove this additional space with the help of `\addcontents`:

```
 \documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vskip-10pt}
\chapter{Organization of this book}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your document class sets the space between chapter entries to a different value, you need to change the `10pt` in my example to this value.

Notice, however, that now the spacing in the ToC is not consistent; perhaps you could reconsider changing the spacing for those entries.